# Keyboard not responding on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: keyboard, 18.04

So after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the keyboard is not responding properly. Although at the boot-up when I have to type my password for disk encryption, it works fine. But after login to Ubuntu, it doesn’t. For example, backspace doesn't respond to me pressing it. Sometimes it does but often it stops responding at all. Like that, the number on top of the keyboard also stop responding however at the bootup it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the problem:

1. Click the down arrow on the top right corner near the Shutdown sign
2. Go to Settings
3. Click on Universal Access
4. Go down and click on Typing Assist (AccessX)
5. On the pop-up message toggle Bounce Keys to ON

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Unfortunately, this is a duplicate of the [first existing](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030739/344926) answer

Comment: @Fabby I’d keep this one. It is easier to read, definitely not a Copy-Paste duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out why that was happening. No it is not a keyboard hardware error but rather it is one of the features of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that did this.

So, apparently inside "Universal Access", there is a feature called as 
"Bounce Keys". Out of curiosity a couple of days earlier. I enabled it and due to this, the keyboard wasn't responding as quickly as it usually did.

Now that i have disable the feature, keyboard is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with 18.04, after last update, ubuntu won't boot up. So I go to recovery mode and fix broken packages. Ubuntu now working but the keyboard is not responding. I tried add modify BOOT_IMAGE according to http://stevesubuntutweaks.blogspot.com/2013/10/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working-after.html and reboot still no effect. So I decided to turn off and remove the battery and power plug, wait for several seconds, place the battery power plug back and go to again to see if the default keyboard can work just in BIOS. 
It can work now. So I continue booting with linux and it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Ubuntu thinks your PC is a tablet and diables the keyboard.
The fix below works if the following command gives you any number that is **not** `31` or `32`.

```bsh
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type
```

**How to fix this:** (from https://askubuntu.com/a/1282269/558457)

> There is a bug in recent kernels that disables some laptop keyboards. Mainly Acer and HP so far.  Can usually go to recovery and boot from kernel 5.4.0-42 or use an external keyboard.
>
> Blacklisting the `intel_vbtn` kernel module is a workaround for this, as seen in [Why my laptop's keyboard screwed up since kernel 5.4.0-47 till 5.8.0-20](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280217/)
>
> To implement this, you can either create a new file in `/etc/modprobe.d` with the suffix `.conf` or use the main `blacklist.conf` file. The former may be preferable, since you can then just delete the file when it is no longer required (i.e. when the bug is fixed):
>
> `sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf`
>
> Add a line to the file, optionally with a comment explaining why you are doing this
>
> ```bsh
> # bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
> blacklist intel_vbtn
> ```
>
> Save the file, exit and reboot.