# both shift keys not working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, configuration, diagnostic

i'm using a laptop and my shift keys aren't working, on the same laptop I also have Windows and when I use it both shifts work normally, so it's not a mechanical problem.

can you please help me diagnose and fix this issue 'question mark'

here's the result of xev just holding up the shift key

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
root 0x224, subw 0x0, time 11213734, (61,-16), root62,49),
state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
root 0x224, subw 0x0, time 11213750, (61,-16), root62,49),
state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

i think that the system is interpreting 'at random' that when i press shift and the system identifies it, it comprehend as it was being pressed and released instead just pressed. please need some help fixing this issue, it's impossible to use the keyboard properly with this issue

thanks

Comment: assuming it's a desktop system, I'd start using `xev`

Comment: Please don't add additional detail via comment, if you want people to read it & reply it's best to edit your question and add it there (without the \n or line-breaks, it's not easy to read & you're best interpreting it yourself or comparing it to another device where keyboard works; a *live* system is fine). You can *edit* your own questions.

Comment: done as requested, since im new to ubuntu i'll like to ask for help on discovering the issue, i wouldn't know how to diagnose it.

Comment: face exactly same issues with ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix this by re-installing the input `X` Server’s driver again. But since the keyboard is not working in the first place, this gets a bit tricky. So, here is how you fix the keyboard not working:

Go to settings > Universal Access > Screen Keyboard (enable)

Search for the 'terminal' and type in:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`

Type in your password and hit `enter`.

Once we have the `X` Server keyboard input drivers installed, reboot your System. When the system is back up and running, you should be able to use your keyboard (and mouse).

Comment: I've tried the fix above it didn't work, the keyboard and mouse are working, just the shift keys both left and right that aren't working, and also it's a laptop no USB device

Comment: If that does not work, try [this other solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04/1282269#1282269) I found

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, it was a kernel issue, apparently there are some kernel versions known to create some issues with the keyboard.

Really thanks