# Touchpad & Keyboard Random Behavior

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, mouse, dell, touchpad

I bought a new laptop from dell a couple of months which is Dell Latitude 3510. It came with Ubuntu 18.04, I've removed it and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The problem is that touchpad keeps stopping suddenly for around 5 to 10 seconds and then works again on its own. It also may suddenly increase its speed and stop scrolling for no reason, and when I try to turn off the touchpad it doesn't turn off. The only solution to solve the problem was to suspend Ubuntu and then open it again.

The keyboard also does random things like writing keywords on its own and move the cursor while writing.

I know there are many questions here regarding similar issues. But believe me I tried every single answer here and I was searching for more than 1 month. I posted this question because I really didn't find any solution.

When I run `xinput list` it outputs:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09ED:00 27C6:01E0 Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL09ED:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
```

Then after running `input list-props "DELL09ED:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad"`:

```
Device 'DELL09ED:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (179):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (181): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (312): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (313):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (314):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (315):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (333):  76, 1843, 58, 1021
    Synaptics Finger (334): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (335):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (336):   96
    Synaptics Tap Durations (337):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (338):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (339):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (340):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (341):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (342): 44, 44
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (343): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (344):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (345): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.090868, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (346):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (347):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (348):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (349): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (350):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (351): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (352):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (353): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (354):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (355): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (356):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (357): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (358):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (359): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (360):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (361):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (362):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (363):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (364): 13, 18
    Synaptics Area (365):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (366):  959, 0, 884, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (367): 11, 11
    Device Product ID (305):    10182, 480
    Device Node (304):  "/dev/input/event7"
```

Comment: The problem could be related to : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04