# System Freezes after logging into Ubuntu 20.04- both keyboard & mouse stop working

Tags: keyboard, mouse, freeze

My keyboard & mouse freezes as soon as I log in.

I rebooted into recovery to a root shell prompt and ran `apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all`, but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Means I tried to enter in

Comment: Means I entered in grub menu & then in recovery mode where i entered in root-(Drop to root shell prompt), then i ran the command apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all & rebooted, but in vein.next time when I tried to enter in root through Grub menu it freezes. i think i could define my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would have done anything as this was probably already installed.  Can you edit you question and include more context.  It may help to tell us when the problem started and to give details about your actions in the days leading up to the problem's onset.  Especially include any details about installing/updating/removing software or making any changes to system files or configurations.

Comment: can you share with me any support for system(keyboard & mouse) freeze after reboot

Comment: Can you help with the issue of system freeze, after reboot both keyboard & mouse freezes.

Comment: Hi , after restarting the system the system immediately freezes. Keyboard & mouse doesn't work to input anything in the system. 
       I tried to resolve by entering into the grub menu & then trough recovery mode i tried to enter into root option (Drop to root shell menu) & ran the command "apt-get install -y xserver-xorg-input-all" but still after rebooting the system freezes. Again i tried to enter through Grub menu but it freezes. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Whatever mentioned above is the problem, & nature of problem.

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse and keyboard? If you don't want to provide any more information, I can't really help any further.  Others may ask you for additional info to help understand a possible cause which could help with a solution.  I encourage you to collaborate with them.

Comment: what type of other information you required??????? Also my keyboard & mouse works in other system i checked

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue - Check out this as it may have some bearing - apparently the latest kernel is causing the problem; [On-board keyboard and trackpad not working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04/1282269#1282269)